# call function from sql script in oracle

Tags: oracle, function

In this code I am calling this `FSG.REPLACE_STRING` function which has 2 parameters, original string and special characters string. The original string is a select query from a table and special character string is 'A'.

I have written the code:

```
FSG.REPLACE_STRING ( (SELECT CAST(NVL(PRAD_ID            , ' ') AS CHAR(12))
FROM FSG_WRK.FSG_PRCB_AUXDB_PRAD WHERE PRAD_ID= '003204091007'), A );
```

but this is not working.

Comment: what do you have as the output of running script?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to pass the table column value into the function, so you need to restructure your statement:

```
SELECT FSG.REPLACE_STRING (CAST(NVL(PRAD_ID, ' ') AS CHAR(12)), 'A')
FROM FSG_WRK.FSG_PRCB_AUXDB_PRAD
WHERE PRAD_ID= '003204091007';
```

Although the `NVL()` part seems a bit pointless if you're filtering for a specific (not-null) value in the query. Casting to `char` looks suspicious too.

Comment: I used this , but I am getting error ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "FSG.REPLACE_STRING", line 36
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    
*Action:                             I am selecting 20 columns from this select query. Its an exiting code so I am not touching the select statement .

Comment: That's coming from inside your function, and we don't know what that is doing.

Comment: if you're setting the value in the join, you don't need the NVL function